# Grails save() Domain Object actually does a Select?

Tags: android, grails, groovy, save

I am trying to take a JSONObject I posted to my groovy controller.  I can pass the object, see the JSON data and then create a Domain Object out of it.  When I save it to write to the database it does a Select instead.

```
def save = {
    def input = request.JSON
    def instance = new Customers(input)
    instance.save()
}
```

here is my debug sql output

```
Hibernate: 
select
    this_.customers_id as customers1_237_0_,
    this_.customers_default_address_id as customers2_237_0_,
    this_.customers_dob as customers3_237_0_,
    this_.customers_email_address as customers4_237_0_,
    this_.customers_email_address2 as customers5_237_0_,
    this_.customers_fax as customers6_237_0_,
    this_.customers_firstname as customers7_237_0_,
    this_.customers_gender as customers8_237_0_,
    this_.customers_lastname as customers9_237_0_,
    this_.customers_membertype as customers10_237_0_,
    this_.customers_memo1 as customers11_237_0_,
    this_.customers_mname as customers12_237_0_,
    this_.customers_newsletter as customers13_237_0_,
    this_.customers_password as customers14_237_0_,
    this_.customers_point_date as customers15_237_0_,
    this_.customers_telephone as customers16_237_0_,
    this_.customers_total_points as customers17_237_0_,
    this_.customers_username as customers18_237_0_ 
from
    customers this_ 
where
    this_.customers_username=?
```

Don't know what would be causing this.

Comment: could you give an example for "input"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have a unique constraint on username. Grails does a select to check uniqueness since assumed that reading one row is a lightweight action and it's preferable to triggering a unique constraint violation and exception.

An alternative is to remove the unique constraint in the domain class and add the unique constraint manually in the database.

Comment: Yep it was a constraint on the customers_point_date column that was not null and so I just set a default if its not there and viola, inserts work!  Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the issue here is that you end up with as many "check selects" as many `unique` fileds you have in your model. So, if you have two `unique` fields, it'll generate two queries instead of one with `OR`.

Comment: Right, because constraints are run in order - there's no logic to detect that two can be merged into one.

Comment: Thanks! And what about concurrency issues? Does it block entire table or is it possible that other insert will show up between "check select" and our insert?

Comment: There's no locking, so yes there is a small chance that an insert can happen in between.

Comment: Burt, is there no other way around this than your alternative suggestion above? No cleaner way to do it via config?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like :

```
Customers cust = new Customers(input);
println ("cust = "+cust);
cust.save();
```